# Wrong HTML and CSS comments tag on Vue.js project with VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have a problem when using Vue.js with VSCode.

When I'm using VSCode keyboard shortcuts for commenting my code, it always uses "//", even in the template (instead of ) or in the style tags (instead of /* */).

I'm using Vetur and I configured it with the prettier extension.

Here's my settings.json :

```
    
{
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        "vue"
    ],
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
        
    },
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
}
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: the comment delimiters are defined in the language definition

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No solution up to now...

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the exact same problem. Uninstalling this VS Code extension made commenting work as expected for me again:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.vue

Comment: this is the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

for me it was vscode extension "volar" being disabled for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide.

In the `language-configuration.json` file you should be able to set the block comments as follows:

```json
{
  "comments": {
    "lineComment": "//",
    "blockComment": ["/*", "*/"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thank your for your answer but the problem is not the line comment or block comment, it's the html vs CSS vs JS comment....

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after synchronising VS Code with another VS Code instance. Disabling and re-enabling Volar solved the problem for me. Quedos to [@sebastian-jung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5658566/sebastian-jung) for pointing me in the right direction.